# Нарисовать Google pie chart используя данные из файла json

Tags: php, javascript

Есть опрос, при выборе одного из вариантов(`input` типа `radio`) в файл `json` записывается  что было выбрано(переменные `$yes` и `$no`). Проблема в том что сама диаграмма не рисуется, помогите.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

    var data =  new google.visualization.DataView();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
        ['Yes', <?php echo json_encode($yes); ?>]
        ['No', <?php echo json_encode($no); ?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'How are you?'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>    <body>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
 </html>

  <?php
    $vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

    $filename = "data.json";
    $content = file($filename);

    $array = explode(",", $content[0]);
    $yes = $array[0];
    $no = $array[1];

    if ($vote == 0) {
        $yes += 1;
    }if ($vote == 1) {
        $no += 1;
    }

    $insertvote = $yes . "," . $no;
    $fp = fopen($filename,"w");
    fputs($fp,$insertvote);
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Comment: Смотрите, у меня есть два `input` типа `radio`, при выборе одного из них скрипт `php` записывает какой был выбран в `json` файл, записывает в виде двух чисел, например если 2 , 2(по столько раз нажимали на каждый из `input-ов`). `$inputs = $yes.",".$no;`

Comment: @Mbmenes можете сказать пример значений json_encode($yes) и $no ?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Это обычные числа.Например в json файле они записаны через запятую(2, 2)

Comment: @Mbmenes Мой ответ решил Ваш вопрос?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan почти, еще одна просьба и балы ваши. Когда  я делаю `echo json_encode(переменная)`то почему то одна из переменных всегда  выводиться в строкой("2") и диаграмма не рисуется. Сможете ли вы мне помочь?Пхп код скину если нужно

Comment: @Mbmenes я не понял вопрос? или вы не все написали?

Comment: @Mbmenes Дайте мне код того участка я сделаю это для вас?

Comment: `<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

$filename = "data.json";
$content = file($filename);

$array = explode(",", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
 $yes += 1;
}if ($vote == 1) {
 $no += 1;
}

$insertvote = $yes . "," . $no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>` вот скрипт php

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan прошу прощения, как скинуть его в читабельном виде?

Comment: В комментариях нельзя в таком виде)))

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan можете пожалуйста дать какую-то вашу контактную ссылку куда я могу скинуть?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/raz.galstyan

Comment: Попробуйте так когда делате echo json_encode($yes). Вместо этого сделайте так echo floatval(json_encode($yes)).

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan добавил код правкой

Comment: @Mbmenes Получилось?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59448/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-mbmenes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример решения вашего вопроса:
Просто в функции data.addRows значения надо менять под свои нужды:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Percentage'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
      ]);
      data.addRows([
       ['Yes', 4],
       ['No', 3]
      ]);

   var options = {
     title: 'My Daily Activities',
     is3D: true,
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Вашей ошибкой было то что в `arrayToDataTable` есть обязательный параметр `Task`, И значение этих параметров и других примеров можете смотреть [здесь](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut).